# Processing parentheses syntax

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error, processing, parentheses

This might seem like a very simple question, but I am quite confused.
I have an if condition with many conditions in it and I cannot figure out the parentheses syntax to be used in this case. Could anyone give me some tips on how to figure out the proper syntax for this or any other case in which there are that many conditions in an if statement? Thanks!

```
  void collisionEn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < myPlats.length; i++) {
      if (posEx > myPlats[i].xPos) 
        && (posEx+wEx > myPlats[i].xPos) 
          && (posEx+wEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth)  
            && (posEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth)
              && (posEy > myPlats[i].yPos) 
                && (posEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight) 
                  && (posEy+wEy > myPlats[i]yPos) 
                    && (posEy+wEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight)
                      rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses around each ***condition*** are not required (but are allowed). You do have parentheses around each condition, and that's okay.

One set of parentheses ***is*** required around the entire condition, though.

```
if (condition)
```

So in your case, add an opening parenthesis right at the very beginning and a closing parenthesis at the very end, and you'll have it.

```
  if ((posEx > myPlats[i].xPos) 
    && (posEx+wEx > myPlats[i].xPos) 
      && (posEx+wEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth)  
        && (posEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth)
          && (posEy > myPlats[i].yPos) 
            && (posEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight) 
              && (posEy+wEy > myPlats[i]yPos) 
                && (posEy+wEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight))
                  rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
```

Precisely because you then have a lot of parentheses, I recommend removing the optional ones around each condition, if your style guide permits it. They're not necessary and in this case they're adding confusion.

```
  if (posEx > myPlats[i].xPos
    && posEx+wEx > myPlats[i].xPos
    && posEx+wEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth
    && posEx < myPlats[i].xPos + myPlats[i].platWidth
    && posEy > myPlats[i].yPos
    && posEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight
    && posEy+wEy > myPlats[i]yPos
    && posEy+wEy < myPlats[i].yPos + myPlats[i].platHeight)
      rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: I didn't know Processing supported the second type of syntax you suggested. I think I might have misunderstood the book I'm reading, I'll check it out again. Also, the mistake I made is on this line : " && posEy+wEy > myPlats[i]yPos". I forgot to add the point after myPlats[i](.)yPos. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that I do to keep the code simpler is to have some local var representing temporarily the calculations to be tested, latter if e.g you want to add a margin to the test area this can be easily done in just one place, like:

```
 float mpX = myPlats[i].xPos;
 float mpY = myPlats[i].yPos;
 float mpW = mpX + myPlats[i].platWidth;
 float mpH = mpY + myPlats[i].platHeight
 float pEx = posEx+wEx;
 float pEy = posEy+wEy;

 if (  posEx > mpX   &&   pEx > mpX
    &&   pEx < mpW   && posEx < mpW
    && posEy > mpY   && posEy < mpH
    &&   pEy > mpY   &&   pEy < mpH)
 rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

About parenthesis they work in if() just as they work in any other calculation, so you have to mind [precedence of the operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), though it's not common that they are needed inside if statements. But... sometimes they are, especially the precedence between &&, ! and || are to be payed attention